# What are the differences between the 'Emirates A380 Experience' and 'iPILOT' flight simulators in Dubai?

Tags: sightseeing, dubai

The Dubai Mall offers two different flight simulator companies: the [Emirates A380 Experience](http://www.emiratesa380experience.com/) and [iPILOT](http://flyipilot.ae/).

Both offer non-motion flight simulators, one with the Airbus A380 and one with a Boeing 737, but what are the differences between them? Does one have better fidelity or video quality? I've heard that iPILOT has a higher-quality cockpit. Is this true?

Comment: @pnuts Yeah I was torn. More subject-matter expertise over there, but it's more about a tourist attraction than real aviation. If people here think it should go over there, I'll do it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the big difference is that one simulates an A380 and one simulates a 737NG.

Comment: I haven't tried them, but the company behind iPilot is [flightdecksolutions](http://www.flightdecksolutions.com/) and they are very well respected and have some serious equipment. The A380 is more of a marketing thing for Emirates; whereas the FDS equipment can be used for simulation time (for procedural training).

Comment: Thanks @BurhanKhalid. I booked the Emirates one, but am sort of thinking I should have gone with iPilot. It's just a fun afternoon activity during a short stopover in Dubai, so it's not a huge deal either way, and I get that both are tourist attractions, but might as well go with the better one if there are two in the same mall.

Answer (score 2):

From user Burhan Khalid's comment:

> The company behind iPilot is [[Flightdeck Solutions]](http://www.flightdecksolutions.com/) and they are very well respected and have some serious equipment. The A380 is more of a marketing thing for Emirates; whereas the FDS equipment can be used for simulation time (for procedural training).

Comment: Downvoter: if you explain your motivation, I can improve my answer accordingly. Also, [please see this meta thread](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/any-point-in-answering-unanswered-questions-where-comments-have-solved-ops-pro/3481#3481).